# Как удалить стиль, добавленный JavaScript'ом?

Tags: javascript, css

Всем привет, помогите с JavaScript.

Есть JS, который добавляет всем элементам вот такой стиль:

```
style="display: none;"
```

У одного элемента нужно удалить его. Пробовал делать так:

```
$('.myclass').css('display', 'inherit');
```

Но это не работает. Как можно решить эту задачку?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выберите Ваш вариант и пользуйтесь.

1. `$('.myclass').css('display', 'block'); // Делает див видимым(по умолчанию).` 
   Аналог в jQuery - `$('.myclass').show();`
2. `$('.myclass').attr('style', ''); // Именно УДАЛИТ свойство style`

Comment: А как удалить element.style у меня есть <ul class="1"> и кнему добавляется с помощью js  style="display: none;" все вмести имеет такой вид <ul class="1" style="display: none;">

Comment: @Анатолий Вторая строка - `$('.myclass').attr('style', '');` P.S. Класс и идентификатор елементов не могут состоять только из цифр.

Comment: Я название класа с 1 изменил на myclass, но неработает, почему непонимаю.

Comment: @Анатолий может у вас на странице несколько `.myclass` или же присвоение `display: none` происходит после того, как вы присваиваете `$('.myclass').attr('style', '');`?

Comment: .myclass только один, и присвоение display: none происходит после загрузки страницы, про это я чет забил . Вот сам код с JS скрипта, я так понял что после загрузки страницы он запускает функцию initMenu();  Но что тогда делать?

$(document).ready(function() {initMenu();});

Comment: @Анатолий что тогда в `initMenu()`? Лучше обновите свой вопрос и дополните его.

Comment: Ответ нашел, просто добавил Ваш код в конец выполнения функции.

Comment: Чтобы полностью удалить аттрибут можно использовать `$('.myclass').removeAttr('style')`

Comment: @mix пустые строки после цифры в списке Вы зачем оставляете? пожалуйста не делайте так ибо это отвлекает, наводя на мысль о существовании неотформатирвоанного кода в пустой строке. если Вам угодно Вы можете использовать вид `Вариант 1:` и `Вариант 2:` - это будет более логичным.

Answer (score 0):

Будет правильнее не писать дополнительные скрипты, а написать первоначальный скрипт правильно.
Вместо того, чтобы добавлять скрипт, который будет удалять свойство `display:none;`, правильнее изменить первоначальный скрипт не давая ему применить данное свойство к ненужным элементам.
Для этого используйте метод [`:not()`](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%B7_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)(он же [`.not()`](http://jquery-docs.ru/traversing/not/)):

```js
$('div.test:not(.test2)').css("display", "none");
//или
//$("div.test").not(".test2").css("display", "none");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">test</div>
<div class="test test2">test2</div>
<div class="test">test3</div>
<div class="test">test4</div>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6unc9uLw/)